# Button's background attribute doesn't work

Tags: android, xml

**Don't show background color in button. Create for background one xml file and set color and radius in that xml file , why don't show color?
my layout file and xml file`**

```
 <Button
            android:id="@+id/signButton"
            android:layout_width="257dp"
            android:layout_height="53dp"
            android:text="@string/sign_in"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:background="@drawable/sign_in_button"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.564"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.921" />
```

**xml `**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
            <corners android:radius="100dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient android:endColor="#f92c8b" android:startColor="#f6bbd6" />
            <corners android:radius="100dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: I would say because you're using a `<selector>` instead of a `<layer-list>` in your drawable, so only the white rectangle is drawn.

Comment: @Николас <layer-list> too doesn't work

Comment: @Programmer777 are you using a Material Components Theme and which version of Material Components Library?

Answer (score 1):

I would say you need to add android:state_pressed="false" to your second item.
Otherwise you are not providing a background for both states, pressed and not pressed.

Hope it helps.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/white" />
        <corners android:radius="100dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:state_pressed="false">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient android:endColor="#f92c8b" android:startColor="#f6bbd6" />
        <corners android:radius="100dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```